# User logs out of other devices if logs in from elsewhere

Tags: php, cookies

Currently, I have it set up such that, when a user logs into their account, it checks the `cookies` table in the database. If a row already exists in the database for that user, it updates the database and the user's cookie with a new hash. If a row doesn't exist for that user, it sets a new hash in the database as well as sets the cookie for the user.

The issue with this is that, if the user logs in from a different device, it will log them out on any other devices as the hash in the cookies won't match for the other devices.

How can I solve this issue? Would it be better to just, rather than update the hash in the database, keep adding new rows for each time they log in?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if user already exists in database - do not update hash, just use hash from db to set cookie for new user

Comment: I've thought of this as well, but it makes it less secure.

Comment: @Burrows why do you think system will became less secure than it is now?

Comment: An alternating hash is more secure than keeping the same hash forever.

Comment: @Burrows in both cases if man-in-middle intercepts your value - he/she can use it to be logged into your system, so actually regeneration of hash doesn't make system more secure, the better way is to use HTTPS cookies, which are harder to intercept

Answer (score 0):

I'd add new rows for each time they login. Record the timestamp of when they logged in then you can check and remove any expired cookies so you don't have a ton of rows with expired cookie information hanging around. I'd perform this check every time the user logs in.

You also might want to consider storing the IP and/or user agent. Then you could setup a page to display to the user their current sessions and give them the option to revoke them if they want.